# How to create folders with 666 permission using vala?

Tags: embedded-linux, glib, vala

Any user needs to be able to delete files and/or folders created by this embedded-linux root process. 
But this vala source `DirUtils.create_with_parents(folder, 0666)` is creating 0644 folders owned by root. 
The generated c code is `g_mkdir_with_parents (folder, 0666)` and the file-system is ext2.

`chmod 0666 [folder]` works as expected when using a console connected to the target but the typical connection will not use the console and will not be root (the typical connection will be embedded-linux USB).

Adding `system("chmod 0666 folder")` to the vala source was tried as a possible workaround but does not change the permissions of the folder from 644 to 666.

- Is `DirUtils.create_with_parents(folder, 0666)` correct usage?
- If so, is there another workaround I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the `umask`, a default restriction on the permissive of permissions on new files. There is GNU library call [umask()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Permissions.html).